# Expand lv bad magic number in superblock

Tags: lvm

I've expanded of 300 GB a volume on my server by using:

```
lvextend -l +76800 /dev/vg0/simax

lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/vg0/simax
LV Name                simax
VG Name                vg0
LV UUID                v6LxAS-U08H-JfM4-gp34-oQTk-Dlv5-tmuLbs
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time thor.tcpmiss.it, 2013-08-08 09:55:57 +0200
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                495.31 GiB
Current LE             126800
Segments               2
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           253:8
```

but then trying to resize fs:

```
resize2fs /dev/vg0/simax
resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/vg0/simax
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

The server is running debian:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1~bpo70+1 (2015-06-08)
```

I don't know exactly what to do so; here's the output of df:

```
df -Th
Filesystem                Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                    rootfs    3.9G  803M  2.9G  22% /
udev                      devtmpfs   10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                     tmpfs     3.2G  308K  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg0-dom0_root ext4      3.9G  803M  2.9G  22% /
tmpfs                     tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                     tmpfs     6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/shm
/dev/md0                  ext2      496M  121M  350M  26% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-dom0_usr  ext4      4.9G  1.3G  3.3G  28% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg0-dom0_tmp  ext4      3.9G  8.0M  3.7G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg0-dom0_home ext4       42G   48M   40G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/vg0-dom0_var  ext4      298G  4.7G  278G   2% /var
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this command # xfs_growfs /dev/vg0/simax  . I guess your filesystem is xfs

Comment: I am sorry . Your file system is ext4 . But II don't see /dev/vg0/simax in your df .

Comment: Actually, your answer is valid and very probable. Welcome to the site @hp1018

Comment: If you want to find out what filesystem is on a given block device, you can run the following against it: `blkid /dev/vg0/simax` substituting the appropriate block device.